# Folder with no permissions, disappeared

Tags: permissions, folder

I was editing the permissions for a folder on sharepoint, and accidentally gave it no permissions. And error came up, and now the folder is gone.

Is there anyway to salvage the folder?

Thanks

Comment: what was the error btw?

Answer (score 2):

You can login with Site collection administrator or with System account/App pool account to give back the permissions.

Comment: I should have full admin access to the site, is this enough? I think I deleted myself, by taking off folder owners, too.

Comment: Login with site collection admin and check

Comment: @Jay There's a difference between having `Full Control` and being a site collection administrator.  The Site Collection Admin will be able to salvage this situation; ask him or her.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your site's recycle bin for the missing folder.  You can also restore the items from the recycle bin as well.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know there was a recycle folder. However it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

You can check site Collection Recycle Bin as well. It may be there.